# How do I create an array of values from a drop down list?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, autocomplete, drop-down-menu

How do I create an array of values from a drop down list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works instead:

var data[];
$('#ddlCodes option').map(function(i, option) {
data[i] = $(option).val();
});

Answer (score 2):

The following should do it. It will create an array from all the values of your select:

```
var data = $("#theSelect options").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
$('#txtEntry').autocomplete(data);
```

Comment: sorry--that's a no-go. I do get a VS message saying, 'get' is a new reserved word and should not be used as an identifier. Not sure if that's to blame or not.